# Triple integral using cylindrical coordinates, what should theta be?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Currently, solving my problem I am getting a negative answer, leading me to believe that my last integral is incorrect constraints.

My bounds: 
$x^2+y^2=1$

$x^2+y^2=4$

$z=x^2+y^2$

the x-y plane and the solid is to the left of the y-z plane

From this, I'm able to conclude that the part I am integrating is in the second and third quadrant. My problem is that I don't understand what $\theta$ should be.

If we are to integrate the solid in all four quadrant, $\int_0^{2\pi}$

If we are to integrate the solid in the first quadrant, $\int_0^{\pi/2}$

MY ATTEMPT AT INTEGRATING IN SECOND, THIRD QUADRANT: $\int_{3\pi/2}^{\pi/2}$

Should it be: $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}$ instead?

Or $\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 2nd and 3rd quadrants in the $xy$-plane, you should set the $\theta$ bounds as

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}d\theta$$

Note that the angle $\theta$  increases counterclockwise. $\frac\pi2$ is the start of the 2nd quadrant and $\frac{3\pi}2$ is the end the 3rd quadrant.

Comment: Okay! Thanks a bunches for clearing up that for me.